# Add date into text field for date picker

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, c#

I need to add date value into text field for date picker, but I can't find text field element because value for ID (date_f2672867e99141c491f00f20ee45f6d8_I) is still different.

Here is a code for text field:

```
<td class="dxic" onmousedown="return aspxDDMC_MD('date_f2672867e99141c491f00f20ee45f6d8', event)" style="width:100%;"> <input id="date_f2672867e99141c491f00f20ee45f6d8_I" class="dxeEditArea_MetalogixMetropolisBlue dxeEditAreaSys" name="date_f2672867e99141c491f00f20ee45f6d8" onfocus="aspxEGotFocus('date_f2672867e99141c491f00f20ee45f6d8')" onblur="aspxELostFocus('date_f2672867e99141c491f00f20ee45f6d8')" onchange="aspxETextChanged('date_f2672867e99141c491f00f20ee45f6d8')" autocomplete="off" type="text"/> </td>
```

And class="dxic" is on the web page more times. I can't use class name to find element.

I want to add into text field value e.g.: 5/31/2017

Can anyone provide an example how to add value into this text field ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't give exact code, but I can give you some suggestions.

If this is the only input on the form with a name and id that starts with the text 'date_' you can use Linq syntax to find the field you want (this is psuedo-code - I don't have time to look up the exact references):

```
driver.findElements(By.TagName("input")).Where(el -> el.getAttribute("name").contains("date_")).Single();
```

Or broken out a bit more:

```
elements = driver.findElements(By.TagName("input")); // collection of all input elements on the page
dateInput = elements.Where(el -> el.getAttribute("name").contains("date_")).Single();
// Linq syntax - el -> el.GetAttribute() is pulling information from the attributes of each element in the list. The name attribute is probably the easiest one to look at.
// Each name attribute value is a string, so the String.contains() method can be used on it.
// Finally, if there's just one input element on the page that has a name starting with "date_", .Single() returns that one element from the collection.
```

Once you've got the element, you can set the value to whatever you wish.